# android: How to create an hyperlink to a code line using Log.d

Tags: android, logcat

I am learning logging in android code using android studio and emulator

I found that the following command shows a traceback with hyperlink to the code location

```
Log.d("TAG", "Message with stack trace info", new Throwable());
```

the image of logcat with hyperlink is

[image]

How can I create only the hyperlink part in my log message, without any traceback output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, for example:

```
import android.util.Log;

public class Logger {

    public static void log(String tag, String message) {
        String caller = getCallerInfo(new Throwable().getStackTrace());
        Log.d(tag, message + caller);
    }

    private static String getCallerInfo(StackTraceElement[] stacks) {
        if (stacks == null || stacks.length < 1) {
            return "";
        }
        StackTraceElement stack = stacks[1];
        return String.format(" (%s:%s)", stack.getFileName(), stack.getLineNumber());
    }
}
```

And call it from any where in your code

```
Logger.log("Manowar", "Today is the good day to die");
```

Answer (score 1):

As of now the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62793538/11214643) by @Cao Mạnh Quang was not giving me the Hyperlink.

The specific String format required for it's generation is this:

```
return String.format(" %s(%s:%s)", traceE.getClassName(), traceE.getFileName(), traceE.getLineNumber());
```

which is just the same as:

```
return stackTraceElement.toString();
```

so you may as well just do that.

Nothing was working for me...
My guess is that...

**This hyperlink is generated by a preconfigured String specification format.**

this format follows the `className + "(" + fileName + ":" + lineNumber + ")"`
If any of those parameters are missing, the hyperlink will not be generated.

There are a couple questions that arise from this:

Is this specification hard coded as a consensus of each LogCat display (IDE side interacts directly with String)

OR

Is this specification hardcoded into the Java code itself? (Java side interprets String generates hyperlink signal + IDE side interprets hyperlink signal and generates it)

The difference between which of these options is the one, would imply whether hyperlink generation is possible simply by changing the required configuration for the Logcat to generate the link either at IDE config level... OR at Java level.

Maybe it is not possible, and this configuration format cannot be changed....

Btw I am sure there must be some super hacky way to achieve this, maybe a way not so intuitive... or maybe it just requires some digging on the IDE config options...